# Add a generator in a gem for Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator

I have a gem that I need to work with Rails 2 and 3, I am trying to get the generator to work for Rails 2 now, the Rails 3 generator work fine. I have a directory structure like:

```
gem_name
  - generators
    - gem_name
      - gem_name_generator.rb <- Should be Rails 2 generator
      - templates
  - lib
    - generators
      - gem_name
        - gem_name_generator.rb <- Working Rails 3 generator
        - templates
```

I cannot get my generator to show up in `script/generate` or `bundle exec script/generate`

The code for my Rails 2 Generator looks like:

```
class GemNameGenerator < Rails::Generator::Base
  def add_options!(opt)
    opt.on('-k', '--api-key=key', String, "Your API Key") { |v| options[:api_key] = v}
  end

  def manifest
    if !options[:api_key]
      puts "Must pass --api-key"
      exit
    end
    record do |m|
      m.template 'initializer.rb', 'config/initializers/my_gem.rb', :assigns => {:api_key => options[:api_key]}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: sorry i don't have much help to offer in regards to rails 3, but this post was a big help for me getting a generator up in rails 2!